# js are not running on chrome but running on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have mention code and also dynamic code for textbox with js. i am facing problem in chrome while running this code but this same code is running on firefox properly, so please give me some suggestion regarding this code.

1. html code for textbox

   ```
   <td><input class="form-control"  required type='text' id='productname_1' name='productname[]'/></td>
   <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" required  type='text' id='price_1' name='price[]'/></td>
   <td><input class="form-control" required  type='text' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]'/></td>
   <td><input class="form-control" readonly="" required type='text' id='total_1' name='total[]'/> </td>
   ```
2. Dymamic html code for textbox

   ```
   <td><input class='form-control productname12_"+i+"' required type='text' id='productname_"+i+"' name='productname[]'onchange='myFunction()'/></td> <td><input class='form-control' readonly type='text' id='price_"+i+"' required name='price[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control' type='text' required id='quantity_"+i+"' name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input class='form-control'  readonly type='text' required id='total_"+i+"' name='total[]'/></td>
   ```
3. js code

   ```
   function myFunction() {
           var x = document.getElementById('productname_'+j).value;
           //alert(x);
           $.ajax({
                       type:"POST",
                       url:"addplaceorder/getproductprice",
                       data:{'name':x},
                       cache:false,
                       success:function(html){
                           //alert(html);
                           //alert('#price_'+k);
                           $('#price_'+k).val(html);
                       }
                   });

               $('#quantity_'+j).change(function(){
                   var val = $(this).val();
                   var price = $('#price_'+k).val();
                   //alert(name);
                   var total = (val* price);
                   //alert(total);
                   totalamount = totalamount+total;
                   //alert(totalamount);
                   $('#total_'+k).val(total);
                   $('#showtotal').text(totalamount);
               });

               $('#quantity_'+j).keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                   //display error message
                   //$("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                          return false;
                   }
              });

           j++;k++;
       }
   ```

Comment: do you get any errors in the developer tools console - and what do you mean by not running? nothing runs at all? one particular thing isn't working? what basic debugging have you attempted?

Comment: Error in console? The only thing i guess that could make it fails on chrome but not on FF would be the local protocol file

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem

```
var x = document.getElementById('productname_'+j).value;
```

The variable j is not initialized, therefore the value is undefined. I suppose that there is not element with id "productname_undefined". So when you try to read value from that undefined element, you will get an error. Something like "can not read property value of undefined"

PS: It is better to use the `debugger` statements, rather then `alert()`;

Comment: Every browser has a built in tool for developers. You can open it by pressing F12.